# what does -mtime mean in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I've got a working script:

```
#!/bin/bash
find ~/.backups/ -type f -name '*.tgz' -mtime +0.5 -exec rm {} \;
```

Nothing wrong with it. Just wondering what -mtime is and how it's calculated. Can't seem to get a hit on Google.

Comment: Take a look at find's documentation: `man find`

Comment: You can also Google `man find`. Not sure what you googled that didn't get a hit, but googling `find mtime` also turns up lots of helpful links.

Comment: I apparently don't have access to the man files on the only linux/unix machine I have access to ... man: can't open the manpath configuration file /etc/man_db.conf ...

Comment: Go back to Google. Try the search strings I suggested. `-mtime` is an option for the `find` command.

Comment: A perfect use case for [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+~%2F.backups%2F+-type+f+-name+%27*.tgz%27+-mtime+%2B0.5+-exec+rm+%7B%7D+%5C%3B)

Answer (score 1):

From [`man find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

```
-mtime n
       File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the
       comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the
       interpretation of file modification times.
```